# How to repair damage to laminate floor?

Tags: laminate-floor, stain-removal

I was hoping to get some advice on how to repair damage to a laminate floor. Carpet cleaner was used on a mat covering the floor which then soaked through to the laminate. There is now an area of discoloration on the floor similar to a bleach stain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Laminate-floors are tough to fix.  The top is usually very thin, so if washing or light buffing does not remove a stain, replacement usually the only option.  Replacing the mat should hide the stains.  Would google for laminate stain removal, might find something that will work.

Comment: I don't think a stain remover will work in this case - it's almost certainly been bleached rather than stained, so I suspect replacement is the only option.